# How to avoid re-render in React when using framer-motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

```
const App = () => {

  // state here
  const [state,setState] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (item) => {
       setState(prev=> [...prev, item];
  }

  return (
    <>
     <MotionComponent/> // Repeating animation
     <StateComponent handleClick={hancleClick}/> // Update state on click event. This also trigger re-renders on MotionComponent 
    </>

  )
}
```

Question: How to avoid MotionComponent re-rendering when click there are click events on StateComponent?

Comment: Where's the click event handled? In App or in StateComponent?

Comment: @kinduser in App, there is a handleClick function pass down to StateComponent, a click event in StateComponent will update state in App.

Answer (score 1):

> in App, there is a handleClick function pass down to StateComponent, a click event in StateComponent will update state in App.

Parent re-render (in your case `App` re-render) will cause children to re-render as well. If you are not passing any props to `MotionComponent`, wrapping it with `React.memo` will prevent the excessive re-renders.

```
export default React.memo(MotionComponent);
```

Comment: Wow, Thats cool, problem solved!!